# Require Js error after upgrading magento 2.1.6 to 2.2.7

Tags: javascript, magento, requirejs

I upgrade magento version from 2.1.6 to 2.2.7 using command line.After upgrading version i got Require Js file error in console.Can anyone help me ?

I got following error

Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/patches/jquery-ui
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterrormakeError @ require.js:166context.onScriptError @ require.js:1681
jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen so far it looks as though the following files were missing from my project https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2.8/lib/web/jquery/patches